# Different implementation of a templated class method for a particular class template type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class with a method for which I need a different implementation for a specific template type. How do i get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specialise the method for that type. E.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct TemplatedClass
{
    std::string methodA () {return "T methodA";}

    std::string methodB () {return "T methodB";}
    std::string methodC () {return "T methodC";}
};

// Specialise methodA for int.

template<>
std::string TemplatedClass<int>::methodA ()
{
    return "int methodA";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to create a [partial (or full) specialization](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html) for this particular type.

Comment: You’ve got to specialize the whole type though, you cannot just partially specialize member functions. This is implicit in the answer but it could be misunderstood.

Comment: You can get around this limitation by using a base class to provide the default implementation (and making the constructors / destructors of this base class protected to avoid using it).

Answer (score 2):

Timo's answer only allows you to specialize the class as a whole, meaning that the compiler won't automatically copy the member functions from the base type to the specialized type.

If you want to specialize a particular method in the class without re-creating everything else, it's a little more complicated. You can do it by passing a size-zero templated struct as an argument, like this:

```
template<typename T> struct TypeHolder { };

template<typename T> class TemplateBase {
public:
    void methodInterface() {
        methodImplementation(TypeHolder<T>);
    }
    void anotherMethod() {
        // implementation for a function that does not
        // need to be specialized
    }
private:
    void methodImplementation(TypeHolder<int>) {
        // implementation for int type
    }
    void methodImplementation(TypeHolder<float>) {
        // implementation for float type
    }
};
```

The compiler will inline the appropriate `methodImplementation` into `methodInterface`, as well as elide the size-zero struct, so it will be just as if you had done a specialization on the member function only.